# Moving Windows form panel onto another panel merges them together

Tags: .net, winforms, visual-studio

I have a number of `Panel` controls (do not want to use `TabControl`) and only one is visible at a time, but their location overlaps.

In the designer when I move a panel near to another it ends up being part of that panel. I prefer not to place them around the form (it's messy and not enough room with other panels on the form) and set their position in code, I just want to place them and make them visible or hidden.

How do I stop this? i.e. I just want an IDE/editor solution to stop VS doing this.

It does the same for `GroupBox` controls.

thanks.

Comment: It's the nature of `Panel` to be drop target at design-time. If you need a different behavior, you should create a custom control. A `TabControl` which  shows tab headers at design-time but hides the headers at run-time is a good option.

Comment: Well, you could write a [custom designer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.design.controldesigner.aspx) that did not allow dragging and dropping to create nested controls. But this seems like *way* too much work for such a simple problem. Just place them carefully, nudging them into position with the arrow keys if necessary. If you accidentally create a parent-child relationship, just undo it. The form only gets designed once. (I also have to wonder why you have so many different panels. There is rarely a need for that.)

Answer (score 0):

Try just using the arrow keys on the keyboard to move the panels near each other.  Doing this, the panel that is being moved will not snap into the nearby panels.